# Can't launch Mycroft GUI

Tags: mycroft

I've installed everything that was recommended ro run Mycroft AI and I can't seem to launch it.
I don't understand what this means (I'm new to this).
How do I fix this, please?

```
$ mycroft-gui-app
Attribute Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
qrc:/main.qml:38:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/main.qml:37:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/main.qml:36:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/main.qml:35:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/main.qml:34:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/main.qml:33:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/main.qml:225:17: Unable to assign ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_72 to QQuickItem
qrc:/main.qml:252:17: Unable to assign null to QStringList
qml: Trying to connect to Mycroft
/usr/bin/mycroft-gui-core-loader: 8: cd: can't cd to /home/amanda/mycroft-core
qml: Trying to connect to Mycroft
qml: Trying to connect to Mycroft
qml: Trying to connect to Mycroft
qml: Trying to connect to Mycroft
```

Output:

```
$ dpkg -S mycroft-gui
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern
*mycroft-gui*

$ apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S mycroft-gui | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort
-u) 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *mycroft-gui* 

Package files:
  100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      release a=now
  500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
      release o=Docker,a=focal,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
      origin download.docker.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
      release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
      origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
  100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386

Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com 
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: What is mycroft? How did you installed it? What is the output of `dpkg -S mycroft-gui` and `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S mycroft-gui | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u)`?

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the post with the output.  Mycroft is an open source AI from Github. I used the codes they provided to install.

Comment: I would recommend to check [Snap version](https://snapcraft.io/mycroft).